# Why in the svelte component when entering text does not change the text length value, but remains equal to 0/1000?

Tags: svelte

I'm learning Svelte. Wrote a component. When you enter text, the length of the text should be displayed. But for some reason it does not change, but remains equal to 0/1000. If the text length is more than 1000, an error should be shown, but it is not shown. What did I do wrong? Here's the code: [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/focused-beaver-g9fyqs?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FInputArea.svelte%3A16%2C7)

Comment: Include all relevant code **in** the question. Reproductions should be constructed from scratch to be as *minimal* as possible. (Optional links are OK.)

Answer (score 1):

You just didn't bind message the `message` prop of your InputArea component. To make it work, all you have to do is make it a two-way binding like this:

```
<InputArea bind:message={message} load={true} error={showError} />
```